# Drawing a rectangle in an Isometric Map

Tags: c#, xna, isometric

I've been trying to draw a rectangle in an isometric map but I've been failing miseraly for the past 2 hours. I'd really appreciate if someone could give me some help around here.
Here are the desired coordinates that I want to include to make the rectangle and my latest attempt.

```
49,137  50,136  51,135  52,134
 50,137  51,136  52,135  53,134
50,138  51,137  52,136  53,135
 51,138  52,137  53,136  54,135
51,139  52,138  53,137  54,136
 52,139  53,138  54,137  55,136
52,140  53,139  54,138  55,137
 (............................)
(............................)
 (............................)
(............................)
 70,157  71,156  72,155  73,154
70,158  71,157  72,156  73,155
```

I apologize for all this mess but I honestly couldn't figure out any easier way to actually replicate what I've been trying to do.

```
for (ushort a = 0; a <= 208; a++)
            {
                for (ushort b = 0; b <= 208; b++)
                {
                    if (a >= 49 && a <= 73 && b >= 134 && b <= 158 && (((b - a) >= 81) && ((b - a) <= 88)))
                    {
                        ChangeBlockColor(a, b);
                    }
                }
            }
```

## EDIT:

This seems to do the job... However I'm still trying to figure out if there's a cleaner way to do it as this is terrible and doesn't really allow me to make a rectangle giving just a couple variables such as starting coordinates, width and height:

```
for (ushort a = 0; a <= 208; a++)
            {
                for (ushort b = 0; b <= 208; b++)
                {
                    int Dif = b - a;
                    if (Dif >= 81 && Dif <= 88)
                    {
                        if ((Dif == 81 && a >= 53 && a <= 73 && b >= 134 && b <= 154) ||
                            (Dif == 82 && a >= 52 && a <= 73 && b >= 134 && b <= 155) ||
                            (Dif == 83 && a >= 52 && a <= 72 && b >= 135 && b <= 155) ||
                            (Dif == 84 && a >= 51 && a <= 72 && b >= 135 && b <= 156) ||
                            (Dif == 85 && a >= 51 && a <= 71 && b >= 136 && b <= 156) ||
                            (Dif == 86 && a >= 50 && a <= 71 && b >= 136 && b <= 157) ||
                            (Dif == 87 && a >= 50 && a <= 70 && b >= 137 && b <= 157) ||
                            (Dif == 88 && a >= 49 && a <= 70 && b >= 137 && b <= 158))
                        {
                            ChangeBlockColor(a, b);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```